# Functorial Properties Preserved by Natural Isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

Conceptually, functors which are naturally isomorphic should have the same functorial properties e.g exactness, (co)continuity, etc. Thus, ideally, I'd hope for a precise definition of a *functorial property* and a meta theorem along the lines of

> Naturally isomorphic functors have the same functorial properties.

Is there such a definition (and a metatheorem), and is what I said even true? Where can I find a precise formulation (or counterexamples)?

Comment: This is clearly true but I've never felt the need to have a precise formulation of it. There are similar metatheorems in other parts of mathematics, e.g. "isomorphic groups have the same group-theoretic properties" and so forth. Roughly speaking any property that can be stated in the "language of categories" only involves statements that are preserved by natural isomorphisms, and maybe one can make this precise but it seems that any particular precisification runs the risk of excluding important examples.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, nonetheless, an example of the definitions and statement would teach me a lot I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A precise definition of such a thing will be essentially tautological. Let me explain this on the (easier) example of groups suggested by Qiaochu Yuan in the comments. A precise (model theoretic) version of the statement

> "Isomorphic groups have the same group-theoretic properties."

will be

> If two models $\mathcal G,\mathcal G'$ of the theory of groups in the first-order language $\mathcal L = \{1,\times,{\cdot}^{-1}\}$ are isomorphic, then for any $\mathcal L$-sentence $\varphi$,
>   $$\mathcal G \models \varphi \iff \mathcal G' \models \varphi .$$

And this is completely trivial, as an isomorphism between $\mathcal L$-structures $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal G'$ is precisely a bijection $f \colon G \to G'$ such that for any formula $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and any tuple $(g_1,\dots,g_n) \in G^n$, 
$$ \mathcal G \models \varphi(g_1,\dots,g_n) \iff \mathcal G' \models \varphi(f(g_1),\dots,f(g_n)). $$

Here we have a precise statement, but we do not *get* anything from it.

---

If you still want to work out the detail of your statement, all you need is to define a suitable (first-order) language and theory for functor.

Comment: Ah, looks like I really should learn some basic model theory. You say "we do not *get* anything from it" though, but it seems there can be some use for such statements - for instance in the context of my question. As an example if $F\cong G$ and $F$ is exact then so is $G$ - this is intuitively clear but I don't see a trivial proof.

Comment: Your claim is incorrect: you are saying two elementarily equivalent groups are isomorphic, but this is false for infinite groups.

Comment: This is the kind of precisification I was worried about: there are many basic and important properties of groups which are clearly preserved by isomorphisms but which cannot be stated in the first-order language of groups. For example, simplicity is not such a property, and neither is the property of being finite (e.g. because neither of these properties are preserved under ultraproducts).

Comment: @ZhenLin Right, I edited. My point still remains : what I want is to show the OP that establishing a precise statement will be more or less tautological. The _hard part_ will be to show that some usual statement is in fact expressible in the chosen language (as Qiaochu Yan said it).

Comment: So you are claiming that elementarily equivalent groups of the same cardinality are isomorphic. This is also false. (Take an ultrapower of $\mathbb{Z}$ and use Löwenheim–Skolem to extract a countable elementary submodel that is non-cyclic.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok, I edited. The OP is not interested by the reciprocal, so let's keep things simple. Once again, I am not writing this answer in order to do group theory but to make a conceptual point, so I hope that now it's ok.

Comment: @Exterior In your example, you will have to show that "$F$ is exact" can be expressed by $F \models \varphi$ for some sentence $\varphi$ and this will be more or less the same (depending on your formalism) as a direct proof of your statement.

Comment: I must disagree with "we do not get anything from it". Isomorphism of groups is usually defined as the existence of a bijection that preserves truth of certain very special formulas, a proper subclass of the **atomic** formulas. And from this we get not only preservation of truth of first-order formulas (as stated in the answer) but also for second-order and higher-order formulas.